# Django Query, distinct on foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, django, distinct

Given these models

```
class User(Model):
  pass

class Post(Model):
  by = ForeignKey(User) 
  posted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I want to get the latest `Post`s, but not all from the same `User`, I have something like this:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(public=True) \
        .order_by('posted_on') \
        .distinct("by")
```

But distinct doesn't work on mysql, I'm wondering if there is another way to do it? 
I have seen some using `values()`, but `values` doesn't work for me because I need to do more things with the objects themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since distinct will not work with MySQL on other fields then model `id`, this is possible way-around with using [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef
...
sub_qs = Post.objects.filter(user_id=OuterRef('id')).order_by('posted_on')
# here you get users with annotated last post
qs = User.objects.annotate(last_post=Subquery(sub_qs[:1]))
# next you can limit the number of users
```

Also note that ordering on `posted_on` field depends on your model constraints - perhaps you'll need to change it to `-posted_on` to order from newest on top.

Comment: I'm not sure what subquery is doing here I'll look into it though... so the result here is a bunch of users with last post which kind of answers the question, so I'll mark it answered. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`order_by` should match the `distinct()`. In you case, you should be doing this:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(public=True) \
        .order_by('by') \
        .distinct('by')
```

`.distinct([*fields])` only works in PostgresSQL.

For MySql Engine. This is [`MySQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) documentation in Django:

> Here's the difference. For a normal distinct() call, the database
>   compares each field in each row when determining which rows are
>   distinct. For a distinct() call with specified field names, the
>   database will only compare the specified field names.

For MySql workaround could be this:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef


user_post = Post.objects.filter(user_id=OuterRef('id')).order_by('posted_on')            
post_ids = User.objects.filter(related_posts__isnull=False).annotate(post=Subquery(user_post.values_list('id', flat=True)[:1]))).values_list('post', flat=True)
posts = Post.objects.filter(id__in=post_ids)
```

Comment: This will not work with MySQL DB engine - you'll get `NotSupportedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend`

Comment: MySql does not support distinct by "field name". You can only distinct but not by any particular field.

Comment: in your mysql workaround, I can't see where/how are you making sure the posts have unique users?